# Adding margin/padding to react navigation tabs causes contents to overflow

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-stack

`labelStyle` applied as below causes a gap at the top:

```
const tabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    HomeStack,
    RecipesStack,
    FavoriteStack,
    ProductsStack,
  },
  {
    tabBarOptions: {
      activeBackgroundColor: '#8BC540',
      inactiveBackgroundColor: '#349746',
      activeTintColor: '#F5F4F4', // tab text color
      inactiveTintColor: '#F5F4F4',
      // This messes up the bottom bar
      labelStyle: {
        marginTop: 15,
        marginBottom: 4,
      },
    },
  }
);
```

Here's how it looks:

[image]

I'd like to add padding above icons, between the label and icons and below label.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell this was being caused by fact that I wrapped my app with `SafeAreaView`.

Once I removed `SafeAreaView`, the style below worked:

```
tabBarOptions: {
      activeBackgroundColor: '#8BC540',
      inactiveBackgroundColor: '#349746',
      activeTintColor: '#F5F4F4', // tab text color
      inactiveTintColor: '#F5F4F4',
      tabStyle: {
        paddingTop: 10,
      },
      style: {
        height: 58,
      },
      labelPosition: 'below-icon',
      labelStyle: {
        marginTop: 5,
        marginBottom: 4,
      },
    }
```